# How to change TextView text on DataChange without calling back a TextWatcher listener

Tags: android, textview, textwatcher

Consider:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            s.append("A");
        }
    });
```

If we add a `TextWatcher` to a `TextView`, and I want to append a letter to this `TextView`, every time the user writes a letter in it, but this keeps calling the `TextWatcher` Listener, so on to `StackOverFlow error`, so how can I append text without calling the `TextWatcher` Listener again?

Comment: TypeMismatch: cannot convert from String to Editable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of afterTextChanged says:

*This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, the text has been changed. It is legitimate to make further changes to s from this callback, **but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively**. (You are not told where the change took place because other afterTextChanged() methods may already have made other changes and invalidated the offsets. But if you need to know here, you can use `setSpan(Object, int, int, int)` in `onTextChanged(CharSequence, int, int, int)` to mark your place and then look up from here where the span ended up.*

So, with every `s.append("A")` you `call afterTextChanged()` again and so on.

Comment: I'm not clear why setSpan helps avoid recursion.

Answer (score 32):

It's easy:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    //Any modifications at this point will not be detected by TextWatcher,
    //so no more StackOverflowError 
    s.append("A");
    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Keeping a reference to `editText` inside `TextWatcher` will cause memory leaks, make sure that you will set it to `null` when you are done with `editText` (e.g. host activity when destroyed)

Comment: impressive. Thinking outside the box.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to avoid a stack overflow:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        boolean editing = false;

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!editing){
               editing = true;
               s.append("A");
               editing = false;
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent. Less resource-intensive than other answers.

Comment: Cursor is coming back to initial position

Comment: Key point: set the boolean BEFORE appending or you'll not get your boolean set before another text change event is fired.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. What is the gist of it? Using a flag? That immediately raises the question whether it is thread-safe or reentrant-safe. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28865522/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudocode so you can do this:

Just change the focus...

So like this:

```
tv.isFocusable = false

tv.setText("my new text")

tv.isFocusable = true // Maybe post this to the message queue, so other jobs finish fist.


// Later on in your listener:

if(tv.isFocusable && tv.hasFocus())
    // Do something
else ignore
```

Answer (score -2):

Kotlin Version

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        if (s.toString().isNotBlank()) {

            val formattedValue: String = // Do some formatting

            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this)
            editText.setText(formattedValue)
            editText.setSelection(editText.text.toString().length)
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this)
        }
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) { }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

    }

})
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., a Kotlin version of what? What is the gist of it? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47050257/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).