# How to update the same EditText using TextWatcher?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher, android-textwatcher

In my Android application I need to implement a TextWatcher interface to implement `onTextChanged`. The problem I have is, I want to update the same EditText With some extra string. When I try to do this the program terminates.

```
 final EditText ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 ET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            try
            {
                 ET.setText("***"+ s.toString());
                 ET.setSelection(s.length());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.v("State", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {               
        }
    });
```

My program terminates and even I try to catch the exception like in my code still it terminates.
Does anyone have any idea why this happens and how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: `When I try to do this the program terminates.` that basically means that you should provide the stack trace that can be found in the LogCat. That would help us a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The content of the `TextView` is *uneditable* on the `onTextChanged` event.

Instead, you need to handle the `afterTextChanged` event to be able to make changes to the text.

For more thorough explanation see:  [Android TextWatcher.afterTextChanged vs TextWatcher.onTextChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476848/android-textwatcher-aftertextchanged-vs-textwatcher-ontextchanged)

---

**Note**: Error `onTextChanged`

Obvioulsy, you are causing an endless loop by continuously changing the *text* on `afterTextChanged` event.

From [the ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged%28android.text.Editable%29):

> **public abstract void afterTextChanged (Editable s)**
>   *This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, the text has been
>   changed. It is legitimate to make further changes to s from this
>   callback, but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop,
>   because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again
>   recursively. ...*

- **Suggestion 1**: if you can, check if the `s` is *already* what you want when the event is triggered.

  ```
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
  {    
      if( !s.equalsIngoreCase("smth defined previously"))
           s = "smth defined previously";              
  }
  ```
- **Suggestion 2**: if you need to do more complex stuff (formatting,
  validation) you can maybe use a `synchronized` method like in [this
  post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435661/edittext-not-updated-after-text-changed-in-the-textwatcher)

---

**Note 2** : Formatting the input as partially hidden with *n* stars till the last *4* chars ( ****four)

You can use something like this in *suggestion 1*:

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {    
       String sText = ET.getText().toString()

        if( !isFormatted(sText))
             s = format(sText);              
    }
    bool isFormatted(String s)
    {
     //check if s is already formatted
    }

    string format(String s)
    {
      //format s & return
    }
```

Comment: HI Zorkun, I tried adding same code in the afterTextChanged(Editable s) event... Still it terminates... Do you know any other alternative way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: The s is editable within afterTextChanged(Editable s). But still it can not assigned to the EditText.

Comment: Yes That's true. It causing an endless loop by continuously changing the text on afterTextChanged event. The thing is, I want to hide the first letters in the EditText, With Some character as * and let only last 4 characters to be visible...

Comment: Thanks... Yes can restrict it running over and over with a simple if condition... Thank you very much for your time and help...!!!!

Comment: Cannot convert from String to Editable.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement [Zortkun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9498218/56285) (where the example code is quite broken), this is how you'd use `afterTextChanged()` to update the same `EditText`:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {        
        if (!editable.toString().startsWith("***")) {
            editable.insert(0, "***");
        }        
    }
});
```

Get familiar with the [`Editable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) interface to learn about other operations besides `insert()`.

Note that it's easy to end up in an infinite loop (the changes you do trigger `afterTextChanged()` again), so typically you'd do your changes **inside an if condition**, as above.

As `afterTextChanged()` [javadocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)) say:

> It is legitimate to make further changes to s from this callback, but
>   be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, because any
>   changes you make will cause this method to be called again
>   recursively.

Answer (score 2):

late answer, if someone looking this is how i did it.

- set addTextChangedListener initially
- in one of the call back (say onTextChanged()) remove addTextChangedListener
- Still interested in receiving updates add it back again.

here is the code.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            Log.d("log", "before");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            Log.d("log", "after");
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

            ediText.setText("text you wanted to put");

            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that worked for me

```
etPhoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!s.toString().equals(Utils.getFormattedNumber(s.toString()))) {
                s.replace(0, s.length(), Utils.getFormattedNumber(s.toString()));
            }
        }
    });
```

where `Utils.getFormattedPhoneNumber()` is your method returning a formatted number